# shell script to validate the network connection between database and sqoop

Tags: database, bash, shell, sqoop, hana

I need a shell script which help to validate the network connection between database and sqoop. Before sqoop happens i need to validate this connectivity.

i.e. if the connection is 'ok' we can proceed for sqoop import/export, else we need to trigger a mail stating that database connectivity is lost.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sqoop-list-tables` or `sqoop-list-databases` tools. 
For example, check output of these commands with names of tables/databases that you expect to see:

```
is_connected=$(sqoop list-tables --connect <connect> | grep -q employees | wc -l)
if [ "$is_connected" -ne "0" ]; then
    # send error mail
else
    # sqoop import
fi
```